# Flatpak repository error on 23.10

Tags: repository, 23.10, flatpak

so I have removed snap and installed flatpak.

After `flatpak list` the following pkg's are installed

```
Name            Application ID               Version  Branch      Installation
Freedesktop Pl… org.freedesktop.Platform     22.08.20 22.08       system
Freedesktop Pl… org.freedesktop.Platform     23.08.10 23.08       system
Mesa            …desktop.Platform.GL.default 23.3.0   22.08       system
Mesa (Extra)    …desktop.Platform.GL.default 23.3.0   22.08-extra system
Mesa            …desktop.Platform.GL.default 23.3.2   23.08       system
Mesa (Extra)    …desktop.Platform.GL.default 23.3.2   23.08-extra system
openh264        …eedesktop.Platform.openh264 2.1.0    2.2.0       system
Freedesktop SDK org.freedesktop.Sdk          23.08.10 23.08       system
Greenfoot       org.greenfoot.Greenfoot      3.8.2    stable      system
Yaru-prussiang… …tk3theme.Yaru-prussiangreen          3.22        system
Yaru-prussiang… …eme.Yaru-prussiangreen-dark          3.22        system
KDE Applicatio… org.kde.Platform                      5.15-23.08  system
QGnomePlatform  …latformTheme.QGnomePlatform          5.15-23.08  system
QAdwaitaDecora… …oration.QAdwaitaDecorations          5.15-23.08  system
QGnomePlatform… …n.QGnomePlatform-decoration          5.15-23.08  system
Firefox         org.mozilla.firefox          121.0    stable      system
Thonny          org.thonny.Thonny            4.1.4    stable      system
VLC             org.videolan.VLC             3.0.19   stable      system
Bluray Java me… org.videolan.VLC.Plugin.bdj           3-23.08     system
FDK-AAC Encodi… ….videolan.VLC.Plugin.fdkaac          3-23.08     system
Pause Click pl… …olan.VLC.Plugin.pause_click 2.2.0    3-23.08     system
```

#slightly surprised thorny is there as softwar said it was unable to install it

while running
#correct me if im wrong I am assuming the `&&` is another way of entering the pipe character
I am getting the following error.

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

So I tried the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository main restricted universe multiverse
```

which gave the following result.

```
Adding component(s) 'main, restricted, universe, multiverse' to all repositories.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease                     
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease 
Hit:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:6 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease
Hit:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:9 https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease
Ign:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Err:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu mantic Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

As far as I can tell this is what was installed when flatpak was installed and enabled.
Apart from the flatpak software apt being a little slow to download,
#I gather that is common with flatpak from what I have read
It works ok, for an apt that I have seen referd to as "relitivley new software"

I get the odd ocashion where it crashes, but I get that with firefox as well. So I am assuming there are system pkg's that I need to try and find on the flatpak software apt that will sort that out.

I have seen a few guides and posts on how to sort this out but none refering to a situation where the repository is ppa for the flatpak apt on mantic 23.10 for a system that has had snap removed completely.

Therefore I am unsure if the guides and posts I have seen for resolving this kind of error are relevant to this situation.

Since removing Snap the only real issue I have had apart from this error, is a decrease in up/down speed when using the internet, but I am going to put that in another question. I only mention it because I don't know if it is related.

The guide I used to remove snap had some code to `touch` one file to prevent `apt update`
and `apt upgrade` from downloading snap updates, and another piece of code to `nano` a file to prevent snap updates from being inserted in to Firefox.

So I am pretty sure the error in question is not being caused by anything snap related trying to download.

#A pointless question to create an entire knew post about but does anyone know if qtube-dl or playlist-dl are available in flatpak vershions?

Comment: there's a [guide here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/how-to-install-flatpak-on-ubuntu) on installing flatpak. Is this wat you followed?

Comment: That requires a rather long answer to address all those points ... But, basically, that repository doesn't support `mantic` and even if it did, it still wouldn't change a thing as you don't need it since you installed Flatpak without it ... Also adding apt repository branches will not affect Flatpak ... Also Flatpack doesn't install those applications by default ... Hopefully someone with enough time on-hand will clarify all those points in an answer :-)

Comment: Also you have repositories  foe multiple distro's - mantic and jammy - and even debian repo's - which isn't recommended or supported.

Comment: @graham no it was the guide at [https://www.debugpoint.com/how-to-install-flatpak-apps-ubuntu-linux/]

Answer (score 1):

The `mantic` [repository doesn't exist](http://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu/dists/), you can try with `jammy`.

Remove the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:flatpak/stable
```

Add `jammy`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu jammy main"
```

Comment: Thankyou worked like a charm

Comment: @neoisfree Unfortunately Nope ... That will hide the error message but will mess up your installed flatpak the next time you do `apt upgrade` and depending on what other dependencies might be in that repository, it might as well mess up other packages ... So, remove that repository and don't use it on `mantic` please.

Comment: had to reinstall linux. everytime I use terminal before I start, when I finish and as required in between I use  `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` though it completed sucsessfuly on restart the system would not boot. 

I suspect that may be due to repartion of secondary ext4 primary part using mantic repo software and not jammy repo software. 
However I do not know enough yet about the file system and dir structures to know for sure.